# How do I apply sprite position offset before each frame is rendered by cc.Animate action?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to port a game to Cocos2d-x. The sprites that I have are not of the same size and are not aligned. This means that I need to move every sprite for its relative offset from the previous one before it is rendered on the screen.

In Cocos2d-x I am using cc.Animate for sprite animations but I could not find a way to apply the sprite move by its offset for each frame of the animation. Is this possible and how can I do it in Cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your question.

If you want to move sprites and then animate them you can try setting up a schedule and doing that in that method, changing its position by the offset and then animating it.

This may help you: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Chapter_3_-_How_to_Move_a_sprite